# Why is my rear rack shaped like this?

Tags: rack

I recently bought a used bike that had a rack attached to it. Until last night I didn't notice this strangely shaped part on one of the sides of the rack (circled in purple in the picture). This isn't on the other side and it isn't on the rack on my other bike or the rack on my roommates bike either. I believe that this piece was partially responsible for the [issues I had attaching panniers to my rack](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/72131/trouble-securly-attaching-panniers-to-rear-rack).

My question is what is this and what purpose does it serve/why is it a part of my rack?

[image: Image of rear rack showing portion of rack in question]

Edit to add photo of top portion of frame pump holder as well.

[image]

Comment: Does the rack have any brand or maker or model number on it ?  The overall shape is like the Topeak ones, but I wonder if the peg is an aftermarket add-on.   Could you add a photo of the top peg too ?

Comment: I just added a photo of the top peg as well. I looked before and the only words I see anywhere on the rack are "JHT Max 25 kg" hidden on the underside of the rack but no identifiable branding that I can see

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I suspect it is one end of a pump holder. It holds one end of a pump. If my suspicion is true, there should be at the other end of the rack something to hold the other end of the pump. You compress the pump against a spring in the pump to attach it to the rack. This works only for pumps having a spring.

Presumably the pump that came with the bike (if it was an accessory sold bundled with the bike) has long ago gone missing. You may not be able to find a replacement pump of exact the same length.

Comment: I just looked and there is another end higher up that I never noticed! That's interesting, I've seen these on frames but not on a rear rack before. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: Pumps, especially frame pumps from the likes of Silca, Zéfal and others come in many different lengths. A well stocked LBS or online shop may have the correct length.

Comment: I already own a mini pump so i probably won’t buy a frame pump to fit here but it is nice to know it is a possibility

Comment: The pump attached to the rack is only approximately as long as the wheel radius or slightly shorter, i.e. 30 cm or slightly shorter. A frame pump such as Zilca or Zéfal is too long.

Answer (score 6):

It's a pump holder, similar to the one on the down tube in the bike below.

[image: Retro bike]

These are very common here in The Netherlands. The pump has a spring in it, so it can be mounted between its two attachment points by pushing the pump together a bit.

I often look for one on parked bikes nearby whenever I need to patch a puncture in an urban area and I don't have a pump myself.
Unfortunately, because they're detachable, they're also very easily stolen.

Comment: Best to not touch other people's parked bikes.

Comment: It's the Netherlands, you won't get immediately shot for borrowing someones pump.

Comment: When someone finds out you're using their bike pump, they're more likely to help you fix your bike than complain about borrowing their pump for 5 mins, let alone involve the police (or worse). I've had strangers offer help with a mechanical quite often, and never had any negative experience.

Comment: I would rather help a stranger myself than have them borrow my stuff without permission.